# Why is my Celcius to Kelvin Model performing so bad compared to my Celcius to Fahrenheit Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning-model

I am new to tensorflow and I saw an example model which was made as following -

```
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])
model = tf.keras.Sequential([l0])
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
history = model.fit(sampl, sampl2, epochs=500, verbose=False)
```

Now when trained on significantly less data -

```
celsius_q    = np.array([-40, -10,  0,  8, 15, 22,  38],  dtype=float)
fahrenheit_a = np.array([-40,  14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100],  dtype=float)
```

It gave a very close prediction for this data but when I used the following data which is significantly more for celsius to kelvin I get predictions which are very off

```
sampl = np.random.uniform(low=-50, high=50, size=(200,))
sampl2 = sampl+273
```

I get the prediction 267 Kelvin for 22 Celsius.

I increased my epochs to 1000 and now the prediction is bang on

The codes are the same for both so why do I see such disparity?

Comment: First(with 6 instances) it took 500 epochs to overfit then it took 1000 (with 200 instances). BTW - You should `std.` the input and have a smaller Learning Rate.

Comment: @10xAI Thanks, I got this example from an Udacity course this is the first one they take and later introduced overfitting concepts ig that's why they didn't talk about it much and moved on quickly. How would you suggest standardizing the input in this case btw I'm new so not too experienced with this

Comment: Just subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation i.e. `(x - x.mean())/x.std()` . You should check the internet for this.